# How to determine a point in a triangle in a high dimension?

Tags: trigonometry, vector-spaces, euclidean-geometry, triangles

I have 3 points: $(x1, x2, x3) \in R^d$

Given a query point $q \in R^d$, how can I  *efficiently* determine whether $q$ resides inside the triangle that is defined by $(x1, x2, x3)$ ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to solve $ax_1+bx_2+cx_3=q$ with $a+b+c=1$.
Form the augmented matrix with $d+1$ rows and $3+1$ columns:
$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}1&1&1&1\\ x1&x2&x3&q\end{array}\right]$$
Solve it with row reduction.  If there is no solution, it is not even in the plane.  If $a$ and $b$ and $c$ are all positive, it is within the triangle.  If one of them is zero, it is on an edge of the triangle; if two of them are zero, then $q$ is one of the three points $x1,x2,x3$

Comment: Thanks! Is there a name for this method?

Comment: It's called least-squares fit (usually implemented with SVD); high-weight the first row.

Answer (score 0):

You can check that $q$ lies in the same plane as the triangle by checking if e.g. the vectors $(q-x_1)$, $(x_2-x_1)$, and $(x_3-x_1)$ are not linearly independent.

You can then check that $q$ is also bounded by all of the triangle's line segments  by checking that the segments $(q,(x_1+x_2+x_3)/3)$ and $(x_i,x_j)$ don't intersect, for all choices $i,j$ of $1,2,3$.

Comment: Your second paragraph is wrong. There are three regions outside the triangle from which all three vertices are visible.

Comment: You're right! I think the new one works, but if not, feel free to edit it.

Comment: The first condition should satisfy that the rank of the 3 vectors is 2.

How can I check that segments do not intersect?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9997374/5326624 (for example) says how to check segment intersection.